# You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, pdo

My cakephp is giving problem and I do not know how to solve it, I tried to update the vendor but the error continues.

**error.log**

```
    Error: [PDOException] You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances
    Request URL: /
    Stack Trace:
    #0 [internal function]: PDO->__sleep()
    #1 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php(148): serialize(Object(Cake\ORM\Query))
    #2 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Cache/Cache.php(239): Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine->write('cake_views_post...', Object(Cake\ORM\Query))
    #3 src/Controller/PostsController.php(494): Cake\Cache\Cache::write('ViewsPosts', Object(Cake\ORM\Query))
    #4 src/Controller/PostsController.php(57): App\Controller\PostsController->getPostsSidebar()
    #5 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(262): App\Controller\PostsController->initialize()
    #6 [internal function]: Cake\Controller\Controller->__construct(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response), 'Posts')
    #7 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php(79): ReflectionClass->newInstance(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response), 'Posts')
    #8 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(93): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->create(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
    #9 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(83): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
    #10 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #11 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(62): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #12 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #13 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #14 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #15 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(81): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #16 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
    #17 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #18 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #19 webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
    #20 {main}
```

**composer show**

```
    $ composer show
    aura/installer-default                1.0.0
    aura/intl                             1.1.1
    cakephp/bake                          1.2.8
    cakephp/cakephp                       3.3.7
    cakephp/chronos                       1.0.0
    cakephp/debug_kit                     3.3.7
    cakephp/migrations                    1.6.3
    cakephp/plugin-installer              0.0.15
    dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir              0.1
    jakub-onderka/php-console-color       0.1    
    jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.3.2
    jdorn/sql-formatter                   v1.2.17
    mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib          2.8.22
    User-Agent strin...
    nikic/php-parser                      v2.1.1
    psr/http-message                      1.0.1
    psr/log                               1.0.0
    psy/psysh                             v0.7.2
    robmorgan/phinx                       v0.5.3
    symfony/config                        v3.1.6
    symfony/console                       v3.1.6
    symfony/debug                         v3.1.6
    symfony/filesystem                    v3.1.6
    symfony/polyfill-mbstring             v1.2.0
    symfony/var-dumper                    v3.1.6
    symfony/yaml                          v3.1.6
    zendframework/zend-diactoros          1.3.7
```

**EDIT**

**src/Controller/PostsController.php**

```
if (($ViewsPosts = Cache::read('ViewsPosts')) === false) {

    $ViewsPosts = TableRegistry::get('ViewsPosts')->find('all')
        ->select([
            'count' => 'COUNT(*)',
            'Posts.created',
            'Posts.id',
        ])
        ->contain([
            'Posts'
        ])
        ->where([
            'Posts.status'        => 'published',
            'Posts.created >=' => new \DateTime('-7 days')
        ])
        ->group(['posts_id'])
        ->order(['count' => 'desc'])
        ->limit(5);

    Cache::write('ViewsPosts', $ViewsPosts); /// line 494
}
```

**FIXED LINE**

```
- Cache::write('ViewsPosts', $ViewsPosts);
+ Cache::write('ViewsPosts', $ViewsPosts->toArray());
```

Comment: How does the actual code look like? It's hard to give feedback without any code given. when does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by this file:

`src/Controller/PostsController.php` at line `494`

You are calling `Cake\Cache\Cache::write('ViewsPosts', Object(Cake\ORM\Query))` but it doesn't like this because you can't serialize a Cake\ORM\Query (this is probably called `$results` or something, so instead of doing this you will want to do.

`$results->cache('ViewPosts');` which will cache the result for you. You can get more info about this from the CakePHP website

[Caching Loaded Results](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#caching-loaded-results) - content included below as well.

**Caching Loaded Results**

When fetching entities that don’t change often you may want to cache the results. The Query class makes this simple:

```
$query->cache('recent_articles');
```

Will enable caching on the query’s result set. If only one argument is provided to cache() then the ‘default’ cache configuration will be used. You can control which caching configuration is used with the second parameter:

```
// String config name.
$query->cache('recent_articles', 'dbResults');

// Instance of CacheEngine
$query->cache('recent_articles', $memcache);
```

In addition to supporting static keys, the cache() method accepts a function to generate the key. The function you give it will receive the query as an argument. You can then read aspects of the query to dynamically generate the cache key:

```
// Generate a key based on a simple checksum
// of the query's where clause
$query->cache(function ($q) {
    return 'articles-' . md5(serialize($q->clause('where')));
});
```

The cache method makes it simple to add cached results to your custom finders or through event listeners.

When the results for a cached query are fetched the following happens:

1. The Model.beforeFind event is triggered.
2. If the query has results set, those will be returned.
3. The cache key will be resolved and cache data will be read. If the cache data is not empty, those results will be returned.
4. If the cache misses, the query will be executed and a new ResultSet will be created. This ResultSet will be written to the cache and returned.

> You cannot cache a streaming query result.